# PHP - FILES array empty when using upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I have I file upload form that looks like this

```
<form action="" name="edit" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
   <input type="file" name="zipfile">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save">
</form>
```

This basically POSTs to it self. But at the top of the same file I output the `$_FILES` array with `print_r($_FILES);`, but it is empty after I submit the form with a 100 kb file.

I have checked my error.log file in /var/log/apache2, but there is nothing there.

My php.ini file is set to

```
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/tmpdir/
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

But the tmpdir directory remains empty. This directory is set with 775 permissions and even 777 for a test, but same results. I have also, after changing the file, restarted the Apache2 service.

I must be missing something very obvious here?

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php you've an important element missing.

Comment: Check what error you're getting using `$_FILES['zipfile']['error']`. Compare this code with the [standard error messages](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: you need to show us your PHP, since you tagged as such. Too many things can be at fault.

Comment: does the print_r() shows you the right temporary path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag

```
<form action="" name="edit" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="zipfile">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save">
</form>
```